# Create, save a read a cookie using Javascript (and Blackberry WebWorks SDK)

Tags: javascript, cookies, blackberry-webworks

I'm going to develop a Blackberry OS 5 + application and I need to store an email, password and language settings.

Blackberry OS 5 doesn't have Local Storage support so I need to use another approach. Somewhere I read that I can use cookies (password will be stored encrypted).

But my problem is I don't know how to create, save and read a cookie using Webworks SDK and/or javascript.

How can I do it?

Comment: Here is a pretty good explanation of how to access cookies in JavaScript (and three handy helper functions to create / read / save them):  [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). I'm not sure if it's supported by Blackberry OS 5 though.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828735/session-management-in-blackberry-webworks